# is it possible to dump partially filtered fzf result in a file?

Tags: fzf

I often need all the text lines that fzf has suitably filtered. It allows me to scroll through the list. I can select only one of them ( or more by marking them individually).  But I want them all (dumped in a file or piped) for further processing with awk and other commands.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `--multi` option to be able to select more than one. For instance, with:

```
fzf --multi --print0 --bind 'enter:select-all+accept' |
  gawk -v RS='\0' '{something with $0}; END{print NR}'
```

Where pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> selects all and accepts, sending the output NUL-delimited to gawk.

Rather than `accept` on enter, you can also `execute(the awk command with {+f})` or even `preview` the output of `awk` on the selection so you can do more than one selection per invocation of `fzf`.

For instance,

```
fzf --multi --print0 --bind 'enter:select-all+preview(
  awk -v RS="\0" "END{print NR}" {+f})'
```

Would print the number of filtered files in the preview window each time you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted - thank you. I didn't  quite understand the execute with {f} or preview that you mentioned. I would appreciate some examples. Thanks again.

Comment: @elmo, see edit. See also `man fzf` for further information.

Comment: Got it, thanks Stephane